# Using Cordova 5.3.3 cli for Android but unable to upload apk on Google Play Store?

Tags: cordova, google-play, android-security

This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users.

Below is the list of vulnerabilities and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Vulnerability
Apache Cordova
The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.3.5.1. For more information about the vulnerabilities, and for guidance on upgrading Apache Cordova, please see https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/08/04/android-351.html.

Please help. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you updating an old app? or it is a new app?

Comment: I am updating old app which i designed using Eclipse IDE. And now i am trying to update that same app using Cordova Build. Firstly, i imported whole project in eclipse than in libraries Added CordovaLib and then generated signed apk using my old key of my app. @jcesarmobile

Comment: then maybe the old cordova files of the bad version are still in your project

Comment: I got your point. Is that problem due to cordova plugin whitelist. because i have deleted my platforms and all plugins than again created the whole project. The alert which i am getting on my Developer account is:         REASON FOR WARNING: Violation of the dangerous products provision of the Content Policy and sections 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.
The vulnerabilities include a high severity cross-application scripting (XAS) vulnerability. Under certain circumstances, susceptible apps could be remotely exploited to steal sensitive information, such as user login credentials.@j

Answer (score 1):

It looks like two things might be the issue:

1. You are using an old version of cordova. [This](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/updating-apache-cordova-platform-latest-version/) link provides more information. The other option is that you can build your app remotely using [phonegap](https://build.phonegap.com/). This will sort out the cordova version as well.
2. Your `config.xml` specifies a version number. Google play does not let you upload the same version so each time you upload to google play this number has to be incremented.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. But i need to mention:                                                                           1) My cordova is updated for android it is 4.1.1                                                                                2) I imported whole project into eclipse IDE and than generated a Signed Apk.                                                                                                               3) I am trying to update my app with this version. But last time i created my app using eclipse only i.e native way

Comment: Just making sure but if you type `cordova -v` your version is above 4 ? You might try updating to version 5. Also, [this](http://ilee.co.uk/Sign-Releases-with-Cordova-Android/) provides a nice tutorial explaining how to build release versions without the need for eclipse or any other tool. This is the process we use when publishing on the app store.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. But I need to mention that My cordova is updated for android it is 6.1.1 then i submitted to playstore, but it was rejected as vulnerabilities. And How to specify version number in config.xml as i changed in manifest file.